# Can't sync updated iOS applications onto my iPod

Tags: ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Facebook and other iOS 5.0 apps be installed for iPhone 3G on iOS 3.1.2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72010/can-facebook-and-other-ios-5-0-apps-be-installed-for-iphone-3g-on-ios-3-1-2)

I have been trying to download Instagram onto my Ipod.I have had it previously, but i deleted it and now i want to reinstall it again. The problem it that it keeps saying that it isn't compatible because of the version. I think it might be because my ipod is old and the apps are iOS versions...Are there any ways that i can get the previous version of Instagram?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to edit in enough details so that this wouldn't be a duplicate of other questions where newer apps don't run on older OS - please flag this once those edits are in place and we can look at reopening it if needed.