# How can I make iOS 4.3 apps go onto my iPod 2G?

Tags: ios

Last Christmas I was given an iPod 2G and it runs on iOS 4.2.1 and I have found it very hard to find apps that go onto my iPod, is there anyway I can make apps that run on iOS 4.3 an above go onto my iPod?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, due to hardware limitations, Apple has limited how far you can upgrade iOS on particular devices.

See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72010/can-facebook-and-other-ios-5-0-apps-be-installed-for-iphone-3g-on-ios-3-1-2/72017#72017) for a similar situation. Perhaps [this Q/A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35707/how-can-i-make-an-app-think-its-running-on-ios-5) would explain things better as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [whited00r 6](http://www.whited00r.com) that just came out. Whited00r 6 has many features from ios 6 including costom backgrounds, multitasking, and siri on iphone 2g and 3g, and on ipod touch 1g and 2g